# Programmatically select and clear selection on an ADF DVT piegraph

Tags: view, graph, pie-chart, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I am using a pieGraph and doing some page interactions based on clicking on the pie-graph. These work just fine.

`<dvt:pieGraph id="graph1" tabularData="#{dc.bean.tabularData}" dataSelection="single"
                                      selectionListener="#{dc.bean.transfersGraphSelectionListener}"/>`

However I am not able to support the following use cases

1. Clicking outside the graph(or clicking a selected data set again) should cause the pie-graph to lose its selection.
2. Having a clear button on the page which forces the graph to lose its current selection.
3. Programmatically select one of the data sets in the graph

I checked the UIGraph API but couldn't find much information.

Any hints would be really helpful.

Comment: It would help is you tell us your jdev version. What does the selectionListener do? what happens if you set the tabular data to an empty model?

Comment: Hi Timo, thanks for your reply. I am using Jdev 12.1.2 however I am fine with any solution compatible with Jdev11g too.

Comment: My selection listener reads the selection event and finds which area was clicked on 

`transfersGraphSelectionListener(SelectionEvent selectionEvent){
        Set<GraphSelection> selectionSet = selectionEvent.getGraphSelection();
for (GraphSelection selection : selectionSet) {
   if (selection instanceof DataSelection) {
     DataSelection ds = (DataSelection) selection;
     Set seriesKeySet = ds.getSeriesKey().keySet();
     for (Object key : seriesKeySet) {
       Object selectedKey = ds.getSeriesKey().get((String) key))
     }`

Comment: I need to know how to clear the selection in the graph programmatically using a clear button from the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

please add the right code to your original post. this is what your code look like

```
transfersGraphSelectionListener(SelectionEvent selectionEvent){ 
  Set<GraphSelection> selectionSet = selectionEvent.getGraphSelection(); 
  for (GraphSelection selection : selectionSet) { 
    if (selection instanceof DataSelection) { 
      DataSelection ds = (DataSelection) selection; 
      Set seriesKeySet = ds.getSeriesKey().keySet(); 
      for (Object key : seriesKeySet) { 
        Object selectedKey = ds.getSeriesKey().get((String) key)) 
      }
```

Looks like something is missing!

Comment: Hi Timo Hahn, `Object selectedKey = ds.getSeriesKey().get((String)key)` gives me the name of the data row in the graph which was selected. Now if I have a button on the page with an action listener from which I want to clear this selection of the graph then how do I do that? The adf pieGraph has a binding in my bean. I hope my situation is more clear now?